# How do I know which ports to allow over the network security group?

Tags: azure, oracle12c, windows-server-2016

I have Oracle 12c installed on a windows server 2016 in Azure. I have a database populated locally, and need to access it remotely. I have allowed following through firewall within the machine:

```
\dbhome_1\bin\oracle.exe
\dbhome_1\bin\tnslsnr.exe
```

I need to access this database over sql developer on a remote machine. How do I know which ports to allow over the network security group?

Comment: Which ports does Oracle require? I'd guess that ports are pretty well documented by Oracle. And a quick web search for `"oracle 12c ports"` turns up quite a bit...

Comment: I've already added 1521 and 5500 in both the local firewall and azure management portal, but still not able to connect remotely

Comment: @ShantanuPandey If you only want to use PLSQL to connect your sql, you need open port 1521(by default). Do you check your instance is running or your listener is listening?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know which ports to allow over the network security group?

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/lop.1012/install.1012/install/fports.htm).

According to your description, I think you want to use function `SQL*Net 2`, you need open port 1521(by default) on Azure NSG and Widows firewall.

Currently, you need check your instance and listener is listening. Please use [`lsnrctl`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/lsnrctl.htm)

```
lsnrctl status [listener_name]
```

You also could use [`tnsping`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG357) to test connection.

Also, you should check `netstat -ant|findstr 1521`. Please ensure the port is listening on `0.0.0.0`.